# Mobile search on a tag is not updating

Tags: bug, android-app, ios-app, stack-overflow-app

When I search for new active questions under a specific tag in the mobile app, it's showing the most recent question is 2 days old. That same search on a web browser shows dozens of questions just today.

This is for Stack Overflow, the tag I'm searching on is Docker, and the **Stack Exchange mobile app** is version **1.0.95** running on Android.

Comment: Did you try "pull-down refreshing"? The stack exchange app's search feature is awful.

Comment: I have noticed this problem as well. "Pull down refresh" doesn't load any new questions on a tag and hasn't since Friday

Comment: Same problem on iOS. Version 1.6.6.2

Comment: @talonmies yes, I've been doing a pull down refresh with no effect

Comment: It appears to be working again. I'll leave this open for a bit in case one of the SE devs wants to post an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Haven't heard anything from the SO devs, but this appears to have resolved itself this morning. If the devs have a better answer, please post it, otherwise I'll consider this resolved.